# C# Stop the flow of the program and reset it without restarting

Tags: c#, winforms, button, radio-button

I am writing a simple WindowsForm program with radiobuttons, buttons, and a customary implemented InputBox.

**Relevant program logic:** I click one of the radiobutons from the groupbox -> enable button -> clicking button initiates custom inputbox asking for 1 value and Yes/Cancel buttons.

```
|
V
```

If Yes button clicked -> proceed with logic flow

If Cancel button clicked -> popup window appears ("Your input was cancelled, do you want to exit application?") with yes/no buttons

```
    |
    V
```

If Yes button clicked -> Exit the program

If No button clicked -> apply the same logic as if Reset button is clicked, which would reset the whole program without restarting it **<---------This is what I am trying to achieve (all relevant methods are provided below)**

## **What is the problem?**

When I simply click Reset button, it applies all needed actions and stops, waiting for my further input. This is the exact result I am trying to achieve when I click No button in the popup window I mentioned above.

However, this is not the case. During the debug mode, after I clicked No button, it goes through the entire logic of the Reset button like I wanted, **BUT** right after that, it goes into the IF statement *(marked in my buttonGetWorkHours_Click method)*. I don't want that, I want it to stop the flow after applying the logic of Reset button and waiting for my input (radiobutton/button click).

## What I tried

I have searched through several threads here in SO and tried implementing several suggestions. The results of these suggestions are commented out inside inputBoxProcedure method. Also, I was looking for [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258246/how-to-stop-program-executing-further-in-c-sharp), which would give me the right idea. But [they state](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b2d3f56-6641-450e-8ac5-c93b28bcf2fe/restart-my-application-without-closing-down?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs) that it is impossible without reloading. Based on that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398394/c-sharp-how-to-make-my-code-return-back-to-a-starting-point-beginner), I thought about implementing extra variable to use for checking if reset logic was running, but seems unnecessarily complicated.

## ULTIMATE QUESTION:

I saw a test executable, so I know it is POSSIBLE, unlike what posts and threads were saying. Can you please point me in a right direction of how to proceed with it?

## Relevant code snippet methods

For the sake of saving everyone's time I will include only methods relevant to my question.

```
private void buttonGetWorkHours_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (radioButtonJobStatusFull.Checked) 
     {
        inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the full time employee for the week", "40");
     }
     else if (radioButtonJobStatusPart.Checked)
     {
        inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the part time employee for the week", "30");
     }

     //if, else if, else, unrelated to the lines above
     if()    //<----------------the logic goes here after going through the whole Reset button logic
     {}
     else if()
     {}
     else()
     {}
  }

private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //clear all radiobutton selections
      //set all strings to empty
      //disable several buttons and groupboxes
      //hide several labels
  }

private void inputBoxProcedure(string text, string defaulttext)
  {
     InputBoxResult result = InputBox.Show(text, "Hours Entry", defaulttext, new InputBoxValidatingHandler(inputBox_Validating));
     if (result.OK)
     {
        labelHoursWorked.Text = result.Text.Trim();
     }
     else
     {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Input was cancelled. Do you wish to quit the application?", "Input Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
           Close();
        }
        else
        {
           buttonReset_Click(this, new EventArgs());
           //Form fr = new Form();
           //fr.Show();
           //this.Close();
           //Application.Restart();
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the inputBoxProcedure to this:

```
private bool inputBoxProcedure(string text, string defaulttext)
{
    InputBoxResult result = InputBox.Show(text, "Hours Entry", defaulttext, new InputBoxValidatingHandler(inputBox_Validating));
    if (result.OK)
    {
        labelHoursWorked.Text = result.Text.Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Input was cancelled. Do you wish to quit the application?", "Input Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            buttonReset_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            //Form fr = new Form();
            //fr.Show();
            //this.Close();
            //Application.Restart();

            return false; // Added
        }
    }

    return true; // Added
}
```

Notice that the return type `void` becomes `bool` and that two lines of `return` have been added.

In `buttonGetWorkHours_Click` change:

```
if (radioButtonJobStatusFull.Checked)
{
    inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the full time employee for the week", "40");
}
else if (radioButtonJobStatusPart.Checked)
{
    inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the part time employee for the week", "30");
}
```

Into:

```
if (radioButtonJobStatusFull.Checked)
{
    if (!inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the full time employee for the week", "40"))
        return;
}
else if (radioButtonJobStatusPart.Checked)
{
    if (!inputBoxProcedure("Enter the total hours worked by the part time employee for the week", "30"))
        return;
}
```

In this way, after a reset, the funtion `inputBoxProcedure` will return `false`. When the function returns `false` the function `buttonGetWorkHours_Click` will return and thus prevent further excecution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help! I've encountered the same problem before myself :D